# How can I include (user selected - dynamic) columns in select statement and where clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like the users to choose which fields they want to see and which they do not want to see.

Table: Companies(cid, cname, state, project_manager, site_supervisor, elec_engg, mech_engg, hydraulics, .....)

Note: All the columns from project_manager to the last column have the value 'Yes/No'

Lets say the user wants to find the companies that have Project managers and electrical engineers in NSW.

The Query will be:

```
Select cid, cname, project_manager, elec_engg  
from companies  
where state='NSW'  
    AND project_manager='Yes'  
    AND elec_engg ='Yes';
```

I was wondering how can I make this search dynamic. Displaying all job titles in a HTML form and having check boxes next to each job title and with search button. Something like below.

Query:

```
select cid, cname, (dynamic user input of columns) 
from companies  
where state="NSW"  
    AND Dynamic input column1 ='Yes'  
    and Dynamic input column2 ='Yes'  
    AND Dynamic input column3 ='Yes'.....  
    AND Dynamic input columnn ='Yes';
```

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Comment: I'd even suggest removing the image - it doesn't really add detail to your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're just ANDing all the parameters together.  If you can set the name for each HTML the elements in the form exactly what you expect for the column name this should work.  When you get the post back (assuming search submits the form as a post), you can loop through the post values.  I'd create an array of valid columns to check against as a whitelist to avoid ever having a broken query.

Here's an example using oldschool mysql escaping or you to get the idea, but I'd really use PDO with prepared statements to populate the values of the query.  The key is to protect both your where parameters and values when dynamically creating SQL.  Shoot me a message if you're using PDO and would like to see that, but this will give you a place to start:

```
$sql = 'SELECT cid, cname, project_manager, elec_engg FROM companies ';
$whereClause =  null;   

//whitelist of valid where clause parameters
$validParams = array('site_supervisor', 'elec_engg', 'mech_engg', 'hydraulics');

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(array_search($key, $validParams)!==false){ //make sure you use !== and not !=
        if(empty($whereClause)){
            $whereClause = " WHERE ";
        }else{
          $whereClause .= " AND ";
        }

        //IMPORTANT: use whatever you're db needs to escape things or use prepare
        //statement replacement
        $whereClause .= "$key='".mysql_escape_string($value)."' "; 
    }
}
$sql = $sql.$whereClause;
echo $sql;
```

You can also add a loop check for just values of 'Yes' and exclude 'No' values...

As noted below in a comment mysql_escape_string($value) is bad... no doubt, to do this correctly and safely with prepared statements and pdo you would change the code to:

$sql = 'SELECT cid, cname, project_manager, elec_engg FROM companies ';
    $whereClause =  null;

```
//whitelist of valid where clause parameters
$validParams = array('site_supervisor', 'elec_engg', 'mech_engg', 'hydraulics');

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(array_search($key, $validParams)!==false){ //make sure you use !== and not !=
        if(empty($whereClause)){
            $whereClause = " WHERE ";
        }else{
          $whereClause .= " AND ";
        }

        //IMPORTANT: use whatever you're db needs to escape things or use prepare
        //statement replacement
        $whereClause .= " $key=:$key "; 
    }
}
$sql = $sql.$whereClause;
$db = new PDO($someDsnString);  
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(array_search($key, $validParams)!==false){ //make sure you use !== and not !=
    $statement->bindValue(":$key", $_POST[$key]);
    }
}       
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Both the prepared statements on the values and the whitelist on the parameter values will make this query safe.

Comment: -1, for using `mysql_escape_string` especially considering it's flaws and the fact that this query is still vulnerable to SQL injection even after you've used it. Prepared statements will not secure this at all either.

Comment: @Ray, Thanks for your help. I have all the HTML field elements matching with columns in MySQL table. I like the way you have run the loop for where clause, I would like to extend it further. When there's a yes for field name in Where clause that column should be displayed along with company name & location. Any ideas on how to do that. Something like, select cid, cname, elec_engg, hydraulics from companies where branch='NSW' AND elec_engg='YES' AND hydraulics='YES'; TIA

Comment: Joshua has a point, though his statement about prepared statements not protecting it I disagree with.  I've added a PDO version using prepared statements.  If anyone can show an SQL vulnerability with this code, please point it out exactly.

Comment: As for dynamic columns to display, I'd follow the same pattern as above... take the column list an put it into an array called $columnNames.  Then loop through the $_POST Array again and if an entry in $_POST['columnname'] is 'yes' add the 'columnname' to the $columnNames array.   Then call implode on the string with a comma seperator to create a comma seperated string called $columns. Then so something like: $sql = "SELECT $columns $whereClause "

Comment: Sorry, got cut off while editing comment.  Here's the final update--don't forget to upvote my answer if you find it useful!. Create an empty array called $columnNames and add the column names for the company name and location that are used in every query.  Then loop through the $_POST Array again and if an entry in $_POST['columnname'] is 'yes' add the name of the to the $columnNames array.   Once the looping is done call implode on the string with a comma seperator to create a comma seperated string called $columns. Then glue it all together  like: $sql = "SELECT $columns $whereClause "

Comment: @Ray Thanks for your advice on the columns. I'm going try that now. Will get back to you. Just to let you know, I'm a newbie in PHP but I'm passionate about learning it.

Comment: @Ray in your first comment (one with escape function). You have written "You can also add a loop check for just values of 'Yes' and exclude 'No' values". Could you please explain in detail with an example? In the final SQL query I want to include the values with only 'Yes' in the where clause. TIA

Comment: @Ray I'm done. I have successfully written code for dynamic columns and also a loop check for values Yes and No. I followed your first answer. I'll now give a try with your second method. Thanks again.

Comment: Good job, glad it worked out for you!  I cannot stress how much I would recommend learning how to use PDO and prepared statements to move away from the older mysql and mysqli libraries--even though mysqli supports prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

just put the result of each field into a string, so something like

```
  $builderworks = $POST_['builderworks'];
 $hydrolics = $POST_['hydrolics'];
```

then just select from the database using all the string values, just make sure you sanitise the POST data above first using mysql_real_escape_string.

so something like

```
SELECT jobname FROM jobtable WHERE hydrolics='$hydrolics' AND $builderworks='$builderworks'
```

ect ect

so basically  $builderworks etc is whatever has been POSTED in that field, it is stored inside everytime someone submits, so if fo example I went to the form, selected the field builderworks to yes, $builderworks would then equal yes when I hit submit, whatever is stored in each string is then compared using the database query then so if $builderworks has yes inside it, selecting all fields that are equal to $builderworks would select all fields equal to yes, or equal to no if I had selected no in the form.

Comment: -1. This doesn't even attempt to prevent SQL injection and it even mentions `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: can you not read ?? 'then just select from the database using all the string values, just make sure you sanitise the POST data above first using mysql_real_escape_string.' , my code was just a bare example to point the person in the right direction, it wasnt supposed to be a copy of what they needed to do, hence why I said to  sanitise the POST's , makes you wonder if you actually ready what I had put.............

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this on your database layer. It's a really, really bad idea for security, stability and maintainability all at once. Separate your concerns. Your data access layer should not be dependent on your user's permissions and should definitely not be dependent on your view.

Extract your data from your database as you normally would (into a "model" or some other structure) and then selectively show the data of that structure in your rendering layer as needed (the "view").